# how to inject environment into another typescript library class with additional dependencies

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a library, say my-lib, written in typescript which has two classes

my-lib/token-manager.ts

```
export class TokenManager {
    // ...

    log() {
        console.log('From my TokenManager class')
    }
}
```

my-lib/api-connection.ts

```
import { TokenManager } from "./token-manager"

export class ApiConnection {
    constructor(
        private tm: TokenManager,
        environment: any
    ) {
        // ...
        console.log(environment)
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.tm.log()
    }
}
```

I have an angular project in which one of the components need this library, say SigninComponent.

I installed the lib as a dependency

project1/package.json

```
 {
   ...
   "dependencies": {
     ...
     "my-lib": "github:myname/my-lib",   
     ...
   }
   ...
 }
```

project1/src/app/signin.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiConnection } from 'my-lib/api-connection';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-signin',
    templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./signin.component.scss']
})
export class SigninComponent {
    
    constructor(private apiConnection: ApiConnection) {

    }

    onSubmit() {
        // ...
        this.apiConnection.doSomething()
        // ...
    }
}
```

this gives the error on browser console

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: ASSERTION ERROR: token must be defined [Expected=> null != undefined <=Actual]
throwError@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:22105:9
assertDefined@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:22101:15
bloomHashBitOrFactory@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:26573:16
lookupTokenUsingNodeInjector@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:26357:42
getOrCreateInjectable@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:26338:47
ɵɵdirectiveInject@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:33315:38
SigninComponent_Factory@http://localhost:4200/main.js:491:82
...
```

the `api-connection` class knows how to create the TokenManager class, not the environment, i need to provide value for that..

i tried to add the following code in the project1 NgModule declaration, i don't know how to provide the value, let alone make it a singleton..

this is what i wrote in the project1 app.module.ts

```
...
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
...

@NgModule({
    ...
    providers: [
        {            
            provide: ApiConnection,
            useValue: environment
        }
    ],
    ...
})
```

i can not make the lib to depend on @angular/core, i can not use angular's @Inject in that lib

any possibility to provide a value to the constructor of the external lib class such that the class object will be singleton and re-usable in all other component and service classes in the angular project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it, not sure if this is the perfect way, it works

3 changes in my-lib:

**first:** make sure the package.json is properly exporting the classes

my-lib/package.json

```
{
    "name": "my-lib",
    "version": "0.0.12",
    "type": "module",
    "exports": {
        "./token.service": {
            "import": "./token.service.js",
            "types": "./token.service.d.ts"
        },
        "./api-connection.service": {
            "import": "./api-connection.service.js",
            "types": "./api-connection.service.d.ts"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "lint": "tsc"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^5.4.2"
    },
    ...
}
```

**second:** pass the environment to api-connection.service constructor as separate primitives rather than untyped object with properties

my-lib/lib/api-connection.service.ts

```
import { TokenService } from "./token.service"

export class ApiConnectionService {
    private apiHost = ''
    private apiKey = ''

    constructor(
        private tokens: TokenService,
        apiHost: string, 
        apiKey: string
    ) {
        // ...   
        this.apiHost = apiHost
        this.apiKey = apiKey
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

**third:** make sure the tsconfig.json is set to build the esm module properly and generate the output `.js` and `.d.ts` files in the root path

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "lib": ["ES2015", "DOM"],
        "moduleDetection": "force",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "./",
        "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
    },
    "include": [
        "./lib/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": []
}
```

my-lib directory structure looks like this after `npm run build`

```
    my-lib
    |
    |----lib
    |     |
    |     |--api-connection.service.ts          
    |     |--index.ts
    |     |--token.service.ts
    |
    |----node_modules
    |----.gitignore
    |----api-connection.service.d.ts
    |----api-connection.service.js
    |----index.d.ts
    |----index.js
    |----package-lock.json
    |----package.json
    |----README.md
    |----token.service.d.ts
    |----token.service.js
    |----tsconfig.json
```

1 change in angular project project1

properly import the classes and add them to the providers list in app.module.ts file

```
// ...
import { TokenService } from 'my-lib/token.service';
import { ApiConnectionService } from 'my-lib/api-connection.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
// ...
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
       // ...
    ],
    imports: [
       // ...
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: TokenService, useFactory: () => new TokenService() },
        {
            provide: ApiConnectionService,
            useFactory: (
                tokens: TokenService
            ) => new ApiConnectionService(tokens, environment.apiHost, environment.apiKey),
            deps: [TokenService]
        }
        // ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this will let angular know how to construct the dependencies for api-connection.service which is the token.service object. and then construct the api-connection.service.

i first tried useFactory just to construct the api-connection.service but that was giving the same error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: ASSERTION ERROR: token must be defined [Expected=> null != undefined <=Actual]
```

i wish angular has a way to report which class was missing in the error log statement instead of simply saying `token must be defined`. i had to debug the `main.js` file and `vendor.js` file to figure out what webpack and angular are doing.

the angular documentation tells the syntax for useFactory but does not have enough examples for common use cases and i had to refer to other angular libraries to figure out the syntax for providers object that has additional non-angular dependencies